# Downloading windows 10 ISO within 24 hours

Tags: windows-10, download, iso-image, windows-10-upgrade

I recently started a windows 10 ISO download from this website:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

I managed to generate a download link for windows 10 creator's update (single language) and I started the download.

On the page with the link, they have the following message

> Links valid for 24 hours from time of creation.
>
> Links expire: 11/28/2017 7:22:23 AM UTC

So, does this message mean that I have to download the ISO within 24 hours.

Keeping in mind that I have limited bandwidth, I am expecting a minimum download time of 3-4 days.

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ISO image (for build 1709 x64) is 4.4 GB; even at 512 kbps that's still [just 20 hours.](http://downloadtimecalculator.com/)

I would expect that "the link will expire" means the transfer can no longer be *started* after 24 hours – but if it is *already* running, then it should just continue until finished.

The MS download server also supports partial requests; if the connection gets interrupted, download managers and just tools like `wget -c` can resume the same download **even from a different URL.** (It works simply by requesting specific byte ranges, so as long as the file on the server hasn't changed it will carry on without noticing.)

Finally, the same `Win10_1709_English_x64.iso` can be found in other places (that is, some people rehost it on their personal webservers) with no such restrictions.

---

If you do a partial download, or use a non-official source, I'd strongly suggest verifying the hash sums afterwards, to make sure the image was not corrupted in transit… but sadly MS doesn't bother publishing those anymore (they used to).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I can still continue the download without any fears then. Also could you suggest a link regarding the last part of the answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to complete the download and installation without the need of an unofficial source

Comment: I could not download by wget: it told "403 Forbidden"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

The direct download link are valid for 24 hours only from the time of creation. So download within the 24 hours otherwise the links will expire.
But, [a user on another forum (Ratan Mani Uniyal)](https://www.askvg.com/tip-get-direct-download-links-of-windows-10-iso-from-microsoft/) found out a method to continue download even when the downloading time was over 24h.

> I have another way to download the iso image by pausing and continuing it on the next day.
>
> Actually the link is valid for only 24 hours. My internet connection is slow. I used FDM to download the iso. On the first day I paused it at only 314 mb and on the next day when I tried to continue the download, it did not work.
>
> I then went to the download site and repeated the download procedure, this time the download started from 0 bytes. I copied this new download URL and pasted it to my last paused download content, updated the new URL and then started the download. So, the last download started from 314mb----> ---->. Its working.